# shell command line to modify a configuration file

Tags: shell

I searched this but did not find answer for my problem.

I have a configuration file, which has a line like

server_ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx

This file is in every node in a cluster. The server_ip is just an IP address which sometimes needs to change. I understand that it is easy to change the server_ip to a new ip address if the old ip address is given. But I don't want to keep tracking the old IP address. I just want to force the server_ip address to change to a new value. So the point here is that we don't want to use xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx part to recognize this line. Instead we can only use 'server_ip=' as the locator, and after this line being located, we just set the server_ip to a new value.

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the `sed` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GNU sed has an in-place option -i. The command is a simple substitute which replaces each string that matches with the new string. We use double quotes so that we can access the environment variable containing the new address. Because of the double quotes we must escape the $ which denotes the EOL in the match pattern or else the shell would try to see a variable name after it.

I didn't test this, so it's probably wrong, but should get you close. (updated to include OP's fixes.)

```
newIp=1.2.3.4; sed -i bak "s/server_ip=.*\$/server_ip=$newIp/g" configfile
```

Comment: `sed -i` is a GNU extension, not a POSIX-standardized option; the POSIX tool for in-place editing is `ex`. There's also a BSD `sed -i` implementation, which has usage somewhat incompatible with the GNU one.

Comment: Thanks, wasn't aware of that. Amended th answer.

Comment: BTW, one place other than portability where I'd be cautious about this ("this" meaning substitution of variables in sed scripts in general) is that it's open to injection attacks -- an attacker who can change the value of `newIp` in use can add extra sed commands to the script to change other lines in the file as well... or, using the `r` or `w` sed commands, to read or write other files on the system.

Comment: Thanks Peter!  It worked very well indeed. I made a little change of it, like the following sed -i "s/server_ip=.*\$/server_ip=$newIp/g" filename. It's ubuntu so -i workes fine.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Interesting point about the injection. What else than using a variable could one do? Read the new address from a file and hard code the file name?

Comment: Ah yes, the filename was missing, and reading from stdin is nonsense with -i. :-). Nice that it worked.

Comment: @PeterSchneider, that, or not using sed. `awk` provides a safe way to inject variables out-of-band from code, for instance. See the use of awk in the `gsub_literal` implementation in http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/021 for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use SED!

```
echo "server_ip=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" > file.txt
sed 's/server_ip=.*/server_ip=NEW_IP/g' < file.txt  > tmpFile
```

Comment: `cat foo | sed` is just a less efficient way of writing `<foo sed` or `sed <foo`; the ways its semantics differ are all for the worse: the `cat` approach uses a pipeline, which means more setup overhead and slower reading (since you have the `cat` process reading from the file, writing to a FIFO, and `sed` reading from the FIFO, rather than just letting `sed` read from the file directly as the redirection approach would do).

Comment: It was just a quick way to show 'sed' being used.  I'll edit to use the < stdin.